# How Can I Get PayPal Buyer's Billing Address

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I'm implementing a Paypal payment method using their Express Checkout NVP implementation.  After I've sent the buyer to PayPal to log in and confirm the payment, I need to retrieve the billing address they have on file with PayPal for us in saving my order. The GetExpressCheckoutDetails method of the API doesn't return billing address information - only Shipping info, which I already have.  Is there some other method that will return the buyer's billing address information?After

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just use the shipping address for saving the order? You can't pull the billing address because there really isn't a reason you'd ever need it.

Comment: We store shipping and billing address as separate fields for the order.  If the buyer wants to ship the order to an address other than his billing address, we need to know both of them - since that information is held within PayPal, I was hoping to retrieve it from there - are you saying there's no way to pull the buyer's billing address info?

Comment: The shipping address can be different than the billing address though. I suspect Paypal hides it because it could potentially be used in bad ways. I can't find a way to pull it. If a user wants to change his/her shipping information after the order is made, they should email you and you can update your database.

Comment: Actually in further searching, I think I may have answered my own question.  it seems that the NVP method **BAUpdate** will return the buyer's current billing address information if you don't pass a value in the BILLINGAGREEMENTSTATUS field - as per the [API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/BAUpdate_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: "billing address" refers to the postal address at which you receive (credit card) bills. This concept doesn't actually apply to a PayPal account (PayPal ususally isn't extending credit and this doesn't bill most of its users). PayPal has no concept of a "billing address", although it may know the billing address(es) of credit card(s) its users may have attached to their accounts. Some PayPal interfaces return a "billing address" because people stuck in the credit card model think they need one, but it is artificial. I would recommend just copying the shipping address.

Comment: Should have added: the PayPal analogue to shipping=billing is whether or not the address is "confirmed", which PayPal will tell you. If it's a confirmed address PayPal is confident it "belongs" to the payer and will offer greater protections. This is similar to, but better than, being the address at which the user receives credit card bills. (PayPal is much more sophisticated than card companies in making this determination.)